# Django extending user model tutorial isn't work for me

Tags: python, django, model, extend

I've use this tutorial and do exactly what they do:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

my model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime

class Chess(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime(1970,1,1,))
    is_avaliable  = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
    in_progress  = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
```

my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from chess_tournament.models import Chess

class ChessInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Chess
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Chess'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (ChessInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

in managaer.py shell:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
u.username # return 'admin' it's work
u.chess.last_activity # return ERROR (described below)
```

AttrinbuteError: 'User' object has no attribute 'chess'

- but in django admin panel this field are available and works

Please help to figure it out coz I already spent 4 hours for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `Chess` model and add `related_name` to the `user` property.

```
class Chess(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="chess_board")
    # Other Stuff
```

Now you can easily access `last_activity` or any other property:

```
u.chess_board.last_activity
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This would not help. Relations have a default related_name already; in the case of a OneToOneField it's the lower-case name of the model. `u.chess` would work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `u.chess` won't work in this case. It gives `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'chess'`.

Comment: In the question description it's clearly written that `u.chess` doesn't work. @DanielRoseman at least try out the solution before down voting.

Comment: @Aakash, Oh God it's finally work))) Man you genius !!! I've add a related name - and i gonna work))) Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Could it possible that you didn't register Chess model?

Try add `admin.site.register(Chess, ChessAdmin)` at the bottom of admin.py. Of course you might have to create a simple ChessAdmin for display first.

Comment: i din't register chess coz it wosn't in example

Comment: I't doesn't work: now it shows in django admin panel, but I can't get access  to chess from User model

Comment: Oh it seems that I misunderstood your problem. I guess you can see inline Chess model fields in User on the website, right? But your problem is no being able to access Chess from User in shell. "u.chess.last_activity" seems not right to me, since chess is a model instead of an "attribute" of User. So when you used "u.Chess" it went wrong. My guess would be "u.Chess__last_activity", double underscore after "Chess". Let's see if it works.